# API Rest Talend execution promotion : artifactType field

Tags: api, talend, talend-mdm

I am currently developing a DevOps process whose goal is to trigger the execution of a promotion pipeline using the Rest Talend API in the case of promoting tasks from one environment to another.

In the API documentation https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/swagger/swagger-ui.html#/promotions32585832executions there is no information on the field ** artifactType ** concerning the tasks .

While researching, I found that for promoting artifacts the keyword is ACTION. However, I unfortunately have no answer for the keyword used to promote the tasks. I have tried TASK, JOB, STEP and ACTION but it shows me an error in the json.

[image]

[image]

If anyone knows what keyword to use to promote tasks in API Rest, that would help me a lot!

Merci :)

Comment: Could it be "Route", "Service", or "Job" ? those are the terms used on TMC IIRC

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After asking to the Talend suport, the key word was "FLOW" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer for promoting tasks using REST API is "FLOW".